In reinforcement learning policy evaluation, which reward is received?
Assume the agent is in a state $s$ and takes action $a$, intending to move to $s_1$, however the dynamics may drop the agent in $s_1$ or $s_2$: may move to $s_1$ and receive reward $r_1$ with a probability $p_1$, or move to state $s_2$ and receive reward $r_2$ with probability $p_2$.
When calculating $v_{k+1}$ (Sutton eq. 4.4), is it:
(1)  $\pi(a|s) * [p_1 * (r_1 * \gamma * s_1)+ p_2*(r_2 * \gamma * s_2)]$
(2)  $\pi(a|s) * [p_1 * (r_1 * \gamma * s_1)+ p_2*(r_1 * \gamma * s_2)]$
Ie is the reward based on the intention of the agent or the state the agent ends up in?

The reward likely should be based on the dynamics of the environment not the intention of the agent.
Imagine if $r_2$ was a large negative reward and $p_2 > p_1$.  This should be captured in the value of the state.  This way as the values back up the agent can learn a path around a risky set of states.
The most prominent example of this I can think of is epsilon greedy on the cliff grid word.  The agent under high settings of epsilon learns a further path around the cliff to avoid epsilon attempting to explore off of it.  It may have the best intention of walk close to the cliff but under the same epsilon, the agent which is aware of the risk and takes the safer path has a higher average reward.

Depends on the setting, many times you don't know the underlying transition matrix, and thus we resort to a monte carlo estimate of the
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sum \gamma^i r_i]
$$
By running multiple simulations
